# Java App Runs on MacOS but not on Raspberry Pi - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, raspberry-pi

Please note that though other posts asked a similar question, I have exhausted all the answers in those posts. The problem is the following:

I developed a Java application in **NetBeans Ver. 8.1** on the **MacOS Sierra**. The application runs successfully from the NetBeans IDE and the MacOS terminal command line. After acquiring a Raspberry Pi B+, I created a NetBeans project configuration with connectivity to the **Raspberry Pi B+** running the **Raspbian OS**. Therefore, I can now build and deploy to MacOS or the Raspberry Pi from the NetBeans IDE. **However**, the application fails on the Pi when I attempt to run it through either the IDE or via SSH through a terminal command line.

**Kenwood_520S.jar** is the name of the application jar file, **Kenwood_520S** is the name of the **package**, and **Transceiver** is the name of the **class** with the public static main() method.

The command executed from the terminal command line is:

java -cp **Kenwood_520S.jar** **Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**

The error message posted in the debug window of the IDE and in the SSH terminal is the same when attempting to run the application on the Pi, namely:

Error: Could not find or load main class **Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**

I compared the contents of the dist directories and subdirectories along with the jar file created on the MacOS (default configuration) and the Raspberry Pi B+ (Pi configuration). The directories, subdirectories and jar file contents are identical on both platforms. I post the details below:

```
ls dist

Kenwood_520S.jar    
README.TXT      
lib

ls lib

AbsoluteLayout.jar  
commons-lang3-3.5.jar  
HawkBridgeFactory.jar  
JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar  
swing-layout-1.0.4.jar

jar -tf Kenwood_520S.jar

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Kenwood_520S/
Kenwood_520S/AudioConversion$Range.class
Kenwood_520S/AudioConversion.class
Kenwood_520S/Cryptography.class
Kenwood_520S/DateInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/DialogStringEditor.class
Kenwood_520S/DoubleInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/ExceptionWriter.class
Kenwood_520S/FrequencyInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/IntegerInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/Internationalization.class
Kenwood_520S/ModeInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/PowerInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/QRZSearchWebService.class
Kenwood_520S/QSOXML.class
Kenwood_520S/RSTInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/SampleProcessor.class
Kenwood_520S/TimeInputVerifier.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$1.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$10.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$11.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$12.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$13.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$14.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$15.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$16.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$17.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$18.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$19.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$2.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$20.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$21.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$22.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$23.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$24.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$25.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$26.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$27.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$28.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$29.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$3.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$30.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$31.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$32.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$33.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$34.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$35.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$4.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$5.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$6.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$7.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$8.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver$9.class
Kenwood_520S/Transceiver.class
Kenwood_520S/WavAudioPulse$PulseLevel.class
Kenwood_520S/WavAudioPulse.class
Kenwood_520S/WavAudioRecorder.class
Kenwood_520S/WavAudioSample.class
Kenwood_520S/WebServiceListener.class
Kenwood_520S/strings.properties
Kenwood_520S/strings_ar_SA.properties
Kenwood_520S/strings_el_GR.properties
Kenwood_520S/strings_en_US.properties
Kenwood_520S/strings_es_ES.properties
Kenwood_520S/strings_it_IT.properties

jar xf Kenwood_520S.jar
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4

Created-By: 1.8.0_73-b02 (Oracle Corporation)

Class-Path: lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar lib/Hawk
 BridgeFactory.jar lib/JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar lib/commo
 ns-lang3-3.5.jar

X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Main-Class: Kenwood_520S.Transceiver

The version of Java on the MacOS is:

java -version

java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

The version of Java on the Raspberry Pi is:

java -version

java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am suspecting that the difference in behavior is attributable to an environmental difference. The difference in Java versions is more of a remote possibility, but there may be other environmental variables that affect behavior. (I doubt a CLASSPATH difference is the reason since I explicitly indicate it in the -cp command line argument.)

Please note: I successfully created several "Hello World" type applications that run on both platforms and from both the IDE and command line. I did this as part of my investigation of this problem. I am an experienced developer, but Java is a relatively recent addition.

Your time and patience are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here, but unfortunately do not have an immediate solution for the cause of this problem. Furthermore, despite all the detail that I provided in my question, I failed to include an essential fact: This application uses swing and imports javax.

The Java application in question imports javax for swing. There is no javax import for the ARM processor. Therefore, this Java swing application runs on the Mac, but not on the Pi.

The key to understanding the real issue at hand was in executing the java command with the **-verbose** switch.

Please observe a snippet of the results of that command when the application is successfully run from the MacOS terminal command line. There are a great many references to javax along with successful load statements.

**java -verbose -cp Kenwood_520S.jar Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**

[Loaded java.io.FilePermission from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermission$1 from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermissionCollection from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.AllPermission from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.UnresolvedPermission from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.BasicPermissionCollection from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded Kenwood_520S.WebServiceListener from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]
[Loaded java.util.EventListener from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener from file:/Library/Java/Extensions/RXTXcomm.jar]
**[Loaded javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]**
**[Loaded javax.swing.WindowConstants from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]**
**[Loaded javax.accessibility.Accessible from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]**
...
[Loaded Kenwood_520S.Transceiver from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]
...
[Loaded javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.Format from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.NumberFormat from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.DecimalFormat from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.JFormattedTextField$AbstractFormatter from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
...
**[Loaded Kenwood_520S.Cryptography from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]**
...
**[Loaded Kenwood_520S.Transceiver$1 from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]
[Loaded Kenwood_520S.Transceiver$2 from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]
[Loaded Kenwood_520S.Transceiver$3 from file:/Users/steffen/Desktop/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]**
...

Now look at a snippet of the results of that command when the application fails on the Pi:

**java -verbose -cp Kenwood_520S.jar Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**

[Loaded java.io.FilePermission from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermission$1 from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermissionCollection from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.AllPermission from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.UnresolvedPermission from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.BasicPermissionCollection from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded Kenwood_520S.WebServiceListener from file:/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/Kenwood_520S/dist/Kenwood_520S.jar]
[Loaded java.util.zip.Inflater from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.zip.ZStreamRef from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.IOException from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
...
[Loaded java.text.Format$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.MessageFormat$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
**Error: Could not find or load main class Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar]

The entire verbose output from the Pi does not have one reference to javax because upon encountering the import in **Kenwood_520S.Transceiver**, the load fails! The problem was not that the file was unable to be **found**, but rather that it was not able to be **loaded**.

My next step is to find an ARM equivalent for javax - if something like that exists.